# What to do if label is bigger than parent UIVIew?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have two multiline `UILabels`. The parent `UIView` only has a certain size (height) but the labels can contain a long string. What I want is that the first label is always shown (e.g. abbreviated with ... if it gets too long). If there is room the second label should be shown. Again if it's too long it should get abbreviated with ...

This is the constraint I'm currently using: `V:|-5-[title]-0-[description]-(>=0)-|`

In some cases the second label gets cut off like this:

[image: second label is cut off]

What should I do? Do I have to change the constraint? Can I hide the second label somehow? But how should I detect when the label is cut off?

In another case the second label wasn't shown at all. The second label should also not overflow the parent `UIView`. How should one handle such cases?

Comment: the lavender color is the view containing 2 labels?

Comment: @Bhavin: Yes it does contain the two labels.

Comment: ok...and its fixed height view?

Comment: The height is fixed. So I have to use the available space as much as possible.

Comment: ok...so why don't you try to make a view some point smaller to prevent this or  try to set font size 1pt bigger....

Comment: The height of the view has a special meaning (duration of an event). So trying to change the height isn't that much possible, because otherwise the user would notice the difference. Also I don't know when iOS will cut my label. It could work for one case, but not for the other. I'd need a solution which would work for each text length and for a certain parent view height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78518/discussion-between-bhavin-and-testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe rounding occurs somewhere in iOS because the label would fit (one line and then at the end with ...) if there would be 0.75pt more space. So it draws it but it is cut off because of the missing 0.75pt space.

Now I took the following approach:  Calculate if the second label (reference text which should be about one line) would fit in the parent view? And if not hide it. I only have code in C# but you should get the idea:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews ()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews ();

    NSString referenceTextToMeasure = new NSString ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
    // take the font of the description label which was cut off
    CGRect referenceTextRect = referenceTextToMeasure.GetBoundingRect (
        new CGSize(this.Frame.Width, nfloat.MaxValue), 
        NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, 
        new UIStringAttributes () { Font = descriptionLabelFont }, 
        new NSStringDrawingContext ()
    );

    // 5 is the spacing constraint I have on the top
    if ((this.Frame.Height - TitleLabel.Frame.Height - 5) < referenceTextRect.Height )
        DescriptionLabel.Hidden = true;
}
```

Seems to work quite well, though a full test has to be made. You could also use a fixed height instead of referenceTextRect.Height and you would save some calculations. Nevertheless, the way I used allows of adapting the fonts so everything is dynamically calculated.